# React, setting onClick in html via dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs

I have a txt component that renders via dangerouslySetInnerHTML

It has this line:

```
lines[i] = lines[i].replace(capoRegex, "<div class='capo' onClick={this.toggleTranspose()}>$1</div>");
```

But when I click the element, I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.toggleTranspose is not a function
```

How do I call my component's function from dangerouslySetInnerHTML ?

Comment: first of all, do you mean `onClick={this.toggleTranspose}` rather than `onClick={this.toggleTranspose()}`? (I assume toggleTranspose is not returning your onclick handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the parent lifecycle method

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.capo').click(function(e){
        ...
    })
}
```

have a look at this https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/react-component-onclick/162316/3

Answer (score 1):

@victor zadorozhnyy's answer was the right direction. I didn't have jquery, and I needed to access the components `setState` method, so this was my final code:

```
var component = this;
document.getElementById('capo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  transpose = parseInt(e.target.dataset["capo"]);
  component.setState({
    transpose: transpose
  });
}
```